# Transitioning from Local Dask to a Cluster …

Tags: python, dask, dask-kubernetes

I have a simple embarrassingly parallel program that I am successfully running locally on Dask. Yay! Now I want to move it to a cluster and crank up the problem size. In this case, I am using GCP. I have tried it two ways, `GCPCluster()` and `HelmCluster()`, and each offers a different failure path. (I have successfully instantiated GCE computations before. Hence, we can likely assume that I have all of the security/login credentials solved. Networking is likely a different story.) Here's the main routine:

```
from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client, wait, as_completed, LocalCluster
from dask_kubernetes import HelmCluster
from dask_cloudprovider.gcp import GCPCluster
from problem.loop import inner_loop
from problem.problemSpec import problemInit

# gRange = 99
gRange = 12


def phase_transition(client: Client):
    p = problemInit()
    m = p.m
    loop = delayed(inner_loop)

    loops = [loop(int(m[i])) for i in range(gRange)]
    # visualize(loops, filename='delayed_results', format='svg')
    futures = client.compute(loops)
    wait(futures)
    for future, result in as_completed(futures, with_results=True):
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # with LocalCluster(dashboard_address='localhost:8787') as cluster:
    with GCPCluster(projectid='random-words-654321', machine_type='n1-standard-4', n_workers=2) as cluster:
        with Client(cluster) as client:
            phase_transition(client)
```

When using `GCPCluster()`, the system waits for a response from the scheduler. Here are the log messages:

```
Launching cluster with the following configuration: 
  Source Image: projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-minimal-1804-bionic-v20201014 
  Docker Image: daskdev/dask:latest 
  Machine Type: n1-standard-4 
  Filesytsem Size: 50 
  Disk Type: pd-standard 
  N-GPU Type:  
  Zone: us-east1-c 
Creating scheduler instance
dask-837e1ad1-scheduler
    Internal IP: 10.142.0.4
    External IP: 35.237.42.13
Waiting for scheduler to run at 35.237.42.13:8786
```

The `scheduler` system is up, I can `SSH` into it. Looks like some network problem. (BTW, I am running this from PyCharm using a Conda image similar to the one invoked by `daskdev/dask:latest`.) Clearly, we are not even beginning to install local code on the cloud.

This is some kind of problem that experience with Dask and GCP will resolve, experience I don't yet have. Hence, allow me to try a different path through the documentation and start a k8s cluster managed by Helm. The only change to my code is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cluster = HelmCluster(release_name='gke-dask')
    with Client(cluster) as client:
        phase_transition(client)
```

This ran much better. It now has problems finding code on my local machine in a subdirectory, `problem`. Here are the logs:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:65410 -> 8786
Forwarding from [::1]:65410 -> 8786
Handling connection for 65410
Handling connection for 65410
/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/dask-cvxpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py:1140: VersionMismatchWarning: Mismatched versions found
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Package | client        | scheduler     | workers       |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| blosc   | None          | 1.9.2         | 1.9.2         |
| lz4     | 3.1.3         | 3.1.1         | 3.1.1         |
| msgpack | 1.0.2         | 1.0.0         | 1.0.0         |
| numpy   | 1.20.2        | 1.18.1        | 1.18.1        |
| python  | 3.8.8.final.0 | 3.8.0.final.0 | 3.8.0.final.0 |
+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
Notes: 
-  msgpack: Variation is ok, as long as everything is above 0.6
  warnings.warn(version_module.VersionMismatchWarning(msg[0]["warning"]))
Handling connection for 65410
Handling connection for 65410
Handling connection for 65410
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/awd/Projects/Stats285/ExamplePhaseTransition/main_func.py", line 39, in <module>
    phase_transition(client)
  File "/Users/awd/Projects/Stats285/ExamplePhaseTransition/main_func.py", line 28, in phase_transition
    for future, result in as_completed(futures, with_results=True):
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/dask-cvxpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 4336, in __next__
    return self._get_and_raise()
  File "/Users/awd/opt/anaconda3/envs/dask-cvxpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 4327, in _get_and_raise
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 75, in loads
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'problem'
```

In practice, I am looking for help with either problem. I have a slight preference for the `GCPCluster()` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with Fargate. It works on local but not on AWS fargate:

````
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 75, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'userActivity'```

It's apparently linked to a Pythonpath mismatch between client and workers
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).